# Can we create date combination on the basis of two columns in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in SQL tables like following.

```
RateDate    AgeFrom AgeTo   NoOfChild
8/1/2018    0        10      3
8/1/2018    11       17      3
8/2/2018    0        10      3
8/2/2018    11       17      3
8/3/2018    0        10      3
8/3/2018    11       17      3
8/4/2018    0        10      3
8/4/2018    11       17      3
8/5/2018    0        9       3
8/5/2018    10       17      3
8/6/2018    0        10      3
8/6/2018    11       17      3
8/7/2018    0        10      3
8/7/2018    11       17      3
8/8/2018    0        10      3
8/8/2018    11       17      3
8/9/2018    0        10      3
8/9/2018    11       17      3
8/10/2018   0        10      3
8/10/2018   11       17      3
```

I want date range on the basis for Age groups [means we can create any age group]

And I want data in following manner. Can someone please help me in this.

```
FromDate    ToDate  Age From    Age To

8/1/2018    8/4/2018    0       10
                       11       17

8/5/2018    8/5/2018    0       9
                      10        17

8/6/2018    8/10/2018   0       10
                       11       17
```

[SQL QUESTION DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B5Fy.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand the format you want.  It is not in the structure of a SQL table/result set.  You should also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I ma using SQL database

Comment: Your screenshot is showing excel, you could use a excel pivot with grouping. The SQL-Server will always return rows in same format, with LAG you could try to find a solution by NULL values from columns fromdate and todate.

Comment: This is not excel , i put my example with the help of excel only.
Left Side of Excel shows the database data. And at the right side of excel screen shot is the result, that I want from saved data.

Looking for some help.